# Checking for nulls in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dataset on which I'm making a linq query.

```
var results = dtWorkCenters.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.Field<string>("Work_Center") == theWorkCenter && x.Field<string>("Job") == theJob)
            .Select(x => new
                {
                    Operation = x.Field<string>("Job_Operation"),
                    WorkDate = x.Field<DateTime>("Work_Date"),
                    Employee = x.Field<string>("Employee"),
                    SetupHours = x.Field<double>("Act_Setup_Hrs"),
                    SetupDollars = x.Field<double>("Act_Labor_Dollars"),
                    RunHours = x.Field<double>("Act_Run_Hrs"),
                    RunDollars = x.Field<double>("Act_Labor_Dollars")
                });
```

The field Job_Operation is a string int the database, but may contain a null value. The above syntax fails on the null values. How do I protect against nulls in the data?

Comment: Are you sure your problem is with `string` fields? because a `string` can holds `null` values, but `DateTime` and `double` can't.

Comment: Yes, I can remove the string field from the query and it runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you are having with `null` values may be a result of trying to set the value type (`DateTime` and `double`) properties (`WorkDate`, `SetupHours`, etc.) to `null`.

If that is the case, try specifying `Nullable<DateTime>` and `Nullable<double>` as the generic `Field` type by using `DateTime?` and `double?` in your calls to `x.Field<T>` like so:

```
var results = dtWorkCenters.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(x => x.Field<string>("Work_Center") == theWorkCenter 
                                   && x.Field<string>("Job") == theJob)
                  .Select(x => new
                               {
                                    Operation = x.Field<string>("Job_Operation"),
                                    WorkDate = x.Field<DateTime?>("Work_Date"),
                                    Employee = x.Field<string>("Employee"),
                                    SetupHours = x.Field<double?>("Act_Setup_Hrs"),
                                    SetupDollars = x.Field<double?>("Act_Labor_Dollars"),
                                    RunHours = x.Field<double?>("Act_Run_Hrs"),
                                    RunDollars = x.Field<double?>("Act_Labor_Dollars")
                               });
```